# CCD sensor Reset gate and Substrate clocks

Tags: sensor, signal, driver, ccd

I am trying to understand the datasheet on Sony ICX404AL CCD sensor and design a small circuit with it.
However I am a bit confused with  Reset gate and Substrate clock signals.

**Information from the datasheet**
[image: Voltages]

[image: Reset gate clock]
[image: Substrate clock]

VϕRG is specified to be 5v input through 0.1uF capacitance. However an example circuit shows that ϕRG pin is also connected to 15V rail through diode and 100k resistor. A similar but different setup can be seen for ϕSUB pin that is connected to Vertical driver CXD1267AN. Datasheet also notes that DC bias for sub is generated inside the CCD.
[image: Schematic]
I would really appreciate if you could help me understand the following points:

- What is the reason for diode + resistor for ϕRG pin?
- How is the RG signal transferred through 0.1uF capacitor?
- How does a setup for ϕSUB pin work and why are additional components configured this way?

Answer (score 1):

Upon closer consideration of provided table values and waveform it seems that RG pin has following voltage requirements:
VRGH = VDD + 0.6 = ~15.6v // High value
VRGL = VRGH - VϕRG = VRGH - 5v = ~10.6v // Low value

Therefore answers to my questions are:

- Capacitor, diode and resistor form a clamper circuit that shifts 0v-5v input to 10v-15v level (still a bit unsure about a difference of 0.6v with table values)
- The same answer as above
- For SUB pin the required voltage difference (VϕSUB) is 22v and the output from CXD1267A driver is -8v-15v range. This  particular arrangement of components seems to provide the desired waveform:
  [image: LTSpice]

[image: ![enter image description here]